# PropertyReferenceException:No property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

For several days I'm trying to create Spring CRUD application. I'm confused. I can't solve this errors.

Here is the relevant files

Models:-
**State**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class State {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int stateId;

    private String stateCode;

    private String stateName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_CODE")
    private Country country;
}
```

**Country**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int countryId;

    private String countryCode;

    private String countryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    private List<State> stateList;
}
```

**Service, UtilityService**

```
@Service
public interface UtilityService {

    public HashMap<String,String> getListOfCountries();
    public HashMap<String,String> getStateListForSelectedCountry(String countryCode);
}
```

**UtilityServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UtilityServiceImpl implements UtilityService {

    @Autowired
    CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    StateRepository stateRepository;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
public HashMap<String,String> getStateListForSelectedCountry(String countryCode){

        Map<String,String> mapOfStates = new HashMap<>();
        List<State> listOfStates = stateRepository.findAllByCountryCode(countryCode);
        listOfStates.forEach(ele ->{
            mapOfStates.put(ele.getStateCode(),ele.getStateName());
        });

        return (HashMap)mapOfStates;
    }
```

But then I get the following error :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'utilityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stateRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.self.learning.jwtAuthApp.repository.StateRepository.findAllByCountry_Code(java.lang.String)! No property code found for type Country! Traversed path: State.country.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.self.learning.jwtAuthApp.JwtAuthAppApplication.main(JwtAuthAppApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[jwtAuth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[jwtAuth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[jwtAuth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[jwtAuth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.self.learning.jwtAuthApp.repository.StateRepository.findAllByCountry_Code(java.lang.String)! No property code found for type Country! Traversed path: State.country.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.self.learning.jwtAuthApp.repository.StateRepository.findAllByCountry_Code(java.lang.String)! No property code found for type Country! Traversed path: State.country.
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property code found for type Country! Traversed path: State.country.
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:342) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:314) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 63 common frames omitted
```

I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong. 
My Oracle database table structure is:-

Country :-

Country_Id
Country_Name
Country_Code

State :-

State_Id
State_Name
State_Code
Country_Code ( this is the FK)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, formatted as code.

Comment: I have attached the full stack trace. You can now go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception explains in some detail what is going wrong (I added line breaks to make it easier to read):

```
Failed to create query for method 
public abstract java.util.List com.self.learning.jwtAuthApp.repository.StateRepository.findAllByCountry_Code(java.lang.String)! 
No property code found for type Country! 
Traversed path: State.country.
```

What this tells you is that Spring Data tries to create the implementation for the method `findAllByCountry_Code` but can't find a matching property.
Specifically it found the property `country` which is of type `Country` and now fails to find a property `code` in the type `Country`.

If one compares that with your entity one has to agree.
There is no `code` in `Country` there is only a `countryCode` which you probably want to refer to. 
So the correct method name should be

`findAllByCountry_CountryCode`

Alternatively you could rename the property `Country.countryCode` to `Country.code` which in my opinion would would be the better solution since the repeated `country` is really just noise and should be dropped in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.When I make the changes mentioned by you it the application starts correctly.

Comment: But when I go to fetch the State List based on the Country Code(varchar2) I pass as parameter, the sql being generated is:-

`
SELECT
    state0_.state_id        AS state_id1_1_,
    state0_.country_code    AS country_code4_1_,
    state0_.state_code      AS state_code2_1_,
    state0_.state_name      AS state_name3_1_
FROM
    state    state0_
    LEFT OUTER JOIN country  country1_ ON **state0_.country_code = country1_.country_id**
WHERE
    country1_.country_code = :1;
`
 it joins with country id instead of country code. Why is it so?

Comment: This is a completely separate question. Please ask it separately so others have a chance to find it and provide or learn from an answer.

Comment: I could solve it, I did not mention referencedColumnName in @JoinColumn, as I was referencing through a non primary key column.

But I have a question regarding your previous solution. My DB object had Country_Code as column name, my Country model had countryCode, then why it was looking for code in type Country?